# IE9 issue with dropdown selected index changed event fires on key down

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-9, selectedindexchanged, ie-developer-tools

I have drop down list and will have some operations of this drop down selected index changed event but from IE9 each time its fire selected index changed event where key down by key board.
Here is my drop down list,

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:DropDownList ID="drpRelocatedCountry" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpRelocatedCountry_OnSelectedIndexChanged" 
      AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" TabIndex="17"></asp:DropDownList>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

down key should be select the next value from drop down not to fire selected index changed event until tab or go to other control.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have set `AutoPostBack="true"` so whenever you press key down, your SelectedIndexChanged event will be called as you have changed the selection. Not sure.

**Edit-** 
I am not able to reproduce your problem at my end. I copied your code and bind it from codebehind but it is not firing SelectedIndexChanged  on key down.

Comment: Then how to get selected index changed event without 'AutoPostBack="false"'

Comment: the problem is only with IE9 other browsers will work fine, and for selected index changed is only need to called when we tab from the control but here when i just press the down key to show the records it will fire the selected index changed for the first value!!

Comment: Ok , now I got your question. Can you please show us from where you are binding items to this dropdown list

Comment: I am binding items from page load under
`if (!IsPostBack)`

`drpRelocatedCountry.Items.Clear();
CountryList tempList = CountryManager.GetList();
drpRelocatedCountry.DataSource = tempList;
drpRelocatedCountry.DataTextField = "COUNTRYNAME";
drpRelocatedCountry.DataValueField = "COUNTRYID";
drpRelocatedCountry.DataBind();`

Comment: Please see my edits above. Also, areyou using anything else like javascript event, updatepanel, ajax calls etc,because I am not able to reproduce your problem at my end.

Comment: yes i am using `UpdatePanel` my `DropDownList` is under `UpdatePanel`

Comment: You should mention all the necessary things while posting the question. Please show us the updatepanel with drodownlist

Comment: Edited my question with `UpdatePanel`